# Setter Injection not working

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I am doing some examples to understand Injection using NInject...

But ended up with confusion in injection..

Ex:-

Consider the following example:-

```
class Busineesss
{
    FirstInterface targetInter = null;

    [Inject]   //Setter Injection
    public SecondInterface ProInj { get; set; }

    [Inject]  //Ctor Injection
    public Busineesss(FirstInterface inbound)
    {
        targetInter = inbound;
    }

    public void run()
    {
    /*Line:X*/          targetInter.doSomeThing();
    /*Line:Y*/        ProInj.GetSomethingMyName();
    }
}


interface FirstInterface 
{
    void doSomeThing();
}

interface SecondInterface 
{
    void GetSomethingMyName();
}
```

Module and main:

```
public class Module : NinjectModule
{
     public override void Load()
     {
        Bind<FirstInterface>().To<FirstImplementer>();
        Bind<SecondInterface>().To<SecondImplementer>();
     }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StandardKernel std = new StandardKernel();
        std.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        FirstInterface obj =   std.Get<FirstInterface>();

        Busineesss b = new Busineesss(obj);  //Injecting Ctor data here
        b.run();
    }
```

***My Understanding:-***
So, as per my understanding, We have to manually call the root class with necessary data, then the Ninject will solve the remaining dependencies by itself.

1. So, I thought that, In the ***Line:Y*** , it will get the instance of SecondImplementer, since it is defined in the Module.

But I did not get any kind of those things. I am getting Null Exception only at the line ***ProInj.GetSomethingMyName()***.

2. If Ninjector is taking care of injection, then why I should pass the data in the ctor of the root class, in the line ***"Busineesss b = new Busineesss(obj);"***, it should be taken care by itself right..
   So, it should be like, we have to just mention the startup class name...
   This question arised because of the line mentioned in the "My Understanding" section....

Could u friends help me, in understanding this one, So I can grasp a little more....

Thanks in advance..

Comment: if you `new` the object yourself then the container cannot inject any dependencies into it. Try resolving `Busineesss` from the container.

Comment: And why are you using property injection at all? All dependencies should be injected through the constructor, because dependencies shouldn't be optional and property injection causes [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/).

Comment: @Steven: Hi, I am just learning the things. But I will have your input while implementing. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. And if you let your injection classes have one constructor, there is no need to mark them with attributes.

Comment: @qujck : Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes that solves the problem. After doing the line Busineesss busi = std.Get<Busineesss>(), it is solving all dependency.... This one solves my 2 sub questions in this question.

Comment: @qujck: So, I should use Get<>, when I want to solve all the dependencies in that class right.....???

Comment: Basically yes, services with dependencies should be resolved from the container.

Comment: @qujck : Hi, Pls add the comment as reply to the question, so I can upvote and mark it as answer as it may help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are `new`ing up the `Busineesss` service when you should be resolving it from the container. Replacing:

```
FirstInterface obj =   std.Get<FirstInterface>();
Busineesss b = new Busineesss(obj);
```

with:

```
Busineesss b = std.Get<Busineesss>();
```

should solve your problem.